# Comparing time to encrypt data on microcontroller with regular PCs

Tags: security, encryption, embedded, iot

First of all, this is my first post on Stackoverflow, so if this is placed in the wrong forum, or tagged incorrectly, or otherwise do not follow convention ... I apologize.

I am currently writing a popular-science article on security aspects of IoT,from a hardware perspective. As part of this I was thinking about comparing the time and/or power consumption of encrypting a byte of data (or more suitable amount of data) on a 16MHz atmega microcontroller (Arduino UNO) with that of a common laptop processor (let's say an i7 of sorts).

Now, I found data on the microcontroller part ([link1](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/crypto.html), [link2](https://ercim-news.ercim.eu/en119/special/managing-the-trade-off-between-security-and-power-consumption-for-smart-cps-iot-networks)), but I struggle to find a good reference or overview of the same for a regular CPU.

What I am looking for is information on either computational time for encrypting, say a byte with AES-256. (I know there are many different version, any one would suffice) on a standard PC or laptop.

Can anyone here help me out?

Comment: Ironically, a crappy Atmega at 16MHz with horrible code efficiency is likely going to run in circles around a x GHz i7 PC, laughing and pointing fingers at how incredibly slow the PC is. Because an Atmega will have nothing else to do but this calculation, it can be done in deterministic real-time. While a PC has to deal with the slow OS, simultaneously check for 100 useless updates on the internet, download the latest spyware, run some thousand services etc etc. So very likely we are talking about micro- or milliseconds for the little Atmega and hundreds of milliseconds for the PC.

Comment: Thnx for the reply Lundin. I see your point. However, In a real world use case, the MCU will probably have other tasks to do in parallel with encrypting, as encryption has to be applied on data to have any purpose (Thus encryption HW-acellerators are being used). Also, It would be pointless to compare a device "multitasking" with another device that is "single-tasking".

Comment: Regardless, microcontrollers are almost always real-time systems and even if multi-tasking you can often calculate the exact time it takes to execute something, or at least set a deadline upon which the code is guaranteed to have finished. Whereas a PC can in theory execute any algorithm for infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Lundin. Does any one else have a link to where I can read about the time it takes for a laptop/PC to complete the above task?

Comment: You are kind of asking if there is a link where you can read about how long a rope is :)

Comment: I suspect there might be a better chance of getting good answers to this on the Information Security site, https://security.stackexchange.com . There are sure to be some experts there that can provide info about computational complexity and time for various encryption algorithms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across [WolfSSL benchmarks](https://www.wolfssl.com/docs/benchmarks/) several time for the purpose of comparing cryptography speed on different hardware.

They do not seem to provide data for a 16MHz micro controller, but they list a **48MHz Atmel SAMD21** based on an ARM Cortex M0 with a speed of **0.138MB/s** for AES.

In comparison, an **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U** @ 2.4GHz is listed with a speed of **15.911 MB/s** for AES-GCM.

One limitation of these benchmarks is that comparing them strictly is not possible: not much details on how they ran it (bare CPU versus "regular PC"), not always the same data provided (AES (?) for one, AES-GCM for the other).

Comment: Thank you very much @Lou_is! Spot on what I am looking for! Much appreciated.

Comment: SAMD21 can't really be compared with an AVR though, it's hundreds of times faster.